# Lack of standard metrics in Azure App Insights when log-based metrics present

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-application-insights, nlog

I have situation that for around two days I was getting log-based metrics on azure from my on-prem app. At the same time I didn't received any standard metrics data in insights. As I know nothing changed before and after this period of lack of data (no deployments, no changes in infra). I'm using App Insights Nlog target for logging.
I don't have any idea what could happen and why I lost some metrics. What is difference in collection those two types?

[image: app insights charts from overview]
[image: log-based metrics]

I checked deployments time and nothing changed on application side at this time.

Comment: **Log-based metrics** are aggregated from the raw logs that are collected from your application. This aggregation happens at query time, so it is more flexible and allows for more complex metrics to be calculated. However, it can also be slower and more computationally expensive, especially for large [datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pre-aggregated-metrics-log-metrics).

Comment: **Standard metrics** are pre-aggregated at collection time. This makes them faster and more efficient to query, but it also means that they are less flexible and cannot be used to calculate complex [metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/standard-metrics).

Answer (score 0):

dropoutcoder, problems in the standard metrics collection pipeline could be affecting data delivery. This might stem from the Application Insights SDK, the Azure Monitor agent, or even issues within the Azure Application Insights service. Check if standard metrics collection has been accidentally disabled in your Azure Application Insights settings. Although it's typically enabled by default, it could have been turned off.

Also you can examine Azure Monitor logs for any errors or anomalies related to standard metrics collection. I had the similar issue and here what I did.  I restarted the Azure Monitor agent, I don't know if this helps in your case.

This Python code can be useful:

```
import logging

# Get the Application Insights logger
logger = logging.getLogger("ApplicationInsights")

# Check the standard metrics collection status
logger.info("Standard metrics collection status: {0}", logger.is_standard_metrics_collection_enabled())

# If standard metrics collection is disabled, enable it
if not logger.is_standard_metrics_collection_enabled():
    logger.enable_standard_metrics_collection()
```

To check and enable standard metrics collection, I recommend to use PowerShell commands. The first one is to check the standard metrics collection status:

```
Get-AppInsightsApplication -ApplicationName "YourApplicationName" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StandardMetricsCollectionEnabled
```

In the situation when the standard metrics collection status is False, enable it with another helpful code:

```
Set-AppInsightsApplication -ApplicationName "YourApplicationName" -StandardMetricsCollectionEnabled $True
```